# Method to stop page load outdated?

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I want to add a stop-button to my page, which can stop the loading of a page inside an iframe.

Say, if I open www.bbc.com in my iframe, and wan't to stop it from loading half way, without stopping the parent page from loading.

I've found some old posts from 2007-2010 which suggest using JS:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopFrameLoad(); return false;"/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function stopFrameLoad()
{
window.stop(); //NS only
document.execCommand("Stop"); //IE only
}
</script>
```

But it looks like this will only work in IE and NS. Any way to make it work in all browsers?

Also, the above example is from 2010. I was wondering if maybe theres another way to  do it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.stop(); //should work in all major browsers

document.execCommand("Stop"); //is necessary to support IE
```

See also [How to stop page load in html static page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943219/how-to-stop-page-load-in-html-static-page)

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you know how to "point" the script towards a specific frame? As I see it, that script will stop the loading of the page it's placed in - and I need it to stop a iframe located in that page.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried just adding the script to the frame it needs to stop, but without any luck. I can see it tries to do something, but I have a meta refresh tag that it appearantly cannot override. I'll create another question for this. I have ofcourse accepted your answer as you did answer all the questions I asked :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.stop();
```

isn't NS only. it works in all browsers with JQuery.