# Stop page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to stop the body from loading using javascript, and then write something on the body element.

I can do this with:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  document.write('<!--');
  window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = "123";
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert(1); // This won't show
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this works, the `alert` function will never be called.

But the problem is that if there is another comment tag on the head section, such as:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  document.write('<!--');
  window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = "123";
  }
</script>

<!-- other tag -->
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert(1); // This will now show.
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I handle this? It is very important that all the content on the body element, won't load. Not just hidden, but not loaded.

Comment: The only way to guarantee that is to not write out the body element to begin with. The browser might have JavaScript disabled for example.

Comment: What possible reason could you have for doing this? That's the question you never answered [the last time you asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813516/empty-body-element-before-page-renders).

Comment: The duplicate linked from above has been deleted. That said, this should probably be considered a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943219/how-to-stop-page-load-in-html-static-page. (ping @kapa, any chance you could edit the dupe link to fix it?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```js
window.stop()
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/652k265t/)

Note that's DOM Level 0, not part of any specification. And it isn't supported by IE.