# HTML onload popup message

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function FP_popUpMsg(msg) {//v1.0
 alert(msg);
}
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #800080" onload="FP_popUpMsg('test message')">
```

This popup window appears on load of the webpage.  I want to format this so that the user cannot access the page unless they click the OK button in the popup.  Presently they can click the X in the browser (top right) and still get in

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `confirm`, which returns true if the 'ok' button was clicked and false if the close or cancel buttons were clicked.  MDN has a page on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm.  The question at [How to stop page load in html static page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943219/how-to-stop-page-load-in-html-static-page) has some solutions for stopping a page from loading, though they seem hackish and bound to fail at some point.   Another solution to that part of the problem would be to redirect to a dedicated page; see [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery) for more.

A sample solution (pure JS, no libraries used here)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function redirIfNotConfirmed(msg) {
      var confirmed = confirm(msg);
      if (!confirmed) window.location.href = "http://my.website.com/dummy_redir_page";
    }

    redirIfNotConfirmed("click ok to proceed");
</script>
</head>
```